# Maximum call stack size exceeded while binding jqGrid row buttons to Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jqgrid

I have a `jqGrid`, with `edit` and `delete` buttons in each row, that loads data on button click. These **(Edit & Del)** buttons are bind with a Knockout ViewModel. Everything is working fine except when the `button`, that loads `jqGrid` is clicked second time, the data doesn't load and I get:

> Maximum call stack size

The **Model**:

```
function policyModel() {
var self = this;
self.iID = ko.observable();
//other properties...
}
```

its **ViewModel**:

```
function policyViewModel () {

  var self = this;

  self.model = new policyModel();

  self.getPolicies = function () {

    $.jgrid.gridUnload("#tblPolicies"); //if user clicks the view button more than once, it should be unloaded first
    getPolicies();
  }

  self.getPolicy = function() {

    //I want to get the details of row using AJAX call and update model here
    alert('Get: ' + rowID); 
  }

  self.updatePolicy = function () {

    var strPolicy = ko.toJSON(self.model);
    alert(strPolicy); //Send the updated record to server using AJAX call
  }

  self.deletePolicy = function (rowID) {
    alert("Delete: " + rowID); //Delete the clicked row using AJAX call
  }

  //some subscribe functions of observables below this...
}
```

populating the **jqGrid**:

```
function getPolicies() {

$("#tblPolicies").jqGrid({

    url: apiUrl,
    datatype: "json",
    loadonce: true,
    colModel: [
        //Column models for data here....

        //this is where I'm generating row buttons and binging them to Knockout model
        {
            label: 'Del', name: 'delete',
            formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                return '<span class="fa fa-trash"  data-bind="click: deletePolicy.bind($data, ' + options.rowId + ')"></span>'
            },
        },
        {
            label: 'Edit', name: 'edit',
            formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

                return '<span class="fa fa-pencil" data-bind="click: getPolicy.bind($data, ' + options.rowId + ')"></span>'
            }
        },
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
    loadonce: true,
    pager: "#dvPoliciesPager",
    loadComplete: function () {

       /*
       As jqGrid is generated after binding of Knockout, I'm binding it to container table in 'loadComplete' event.
       To avoid rebinding, I'm removing the bindings first using 'cleanNode'.
       */
       ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("tblPolicies"));
       ko.applyBindings(policyViewModel(), document.getElementById("tblPolicies"));
    },
 });
}
```

initializing in **document.ready**:

```
$(function () {

  ko.applyBindings(new policyViewModel());
});
```

and the **HTML**:

```
<input type="button" id="btnUpdatePolicy" data-bind="click: updatePolicy" value="Update Policy"/>

<input type="button" id="btnViewPolicies" data-bind="click: getPolicies" value="View Policies"/>

<div id="dvPoliciesContainer">
  <table id="tblPolicies"></table>
</div>
```

I tried:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764208/knockoutjs-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061522/knockout-mapping-causing-stackoverflow) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535178/how-to-solve-the-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-issue-in-javascript-code) but couldn't get any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is calling the same function in the loop:

```
  self.getPolicies = function () {

    $.jgrid.gridUnload("#tblPolicies"); //if user clicks the view button more than once,
    window.getPolicies(); // <---------this one here
  }
```

I think you want to refer to the jqGrid creator function defined globally.

Comment: `self.getPolicies` and `getPolicies()` are meant to be different functions. the first one is associated with **ViewModel** and the second one is just a helper function but the same names might be causing the problem. Let me fix and and try

Comment: *facepalm* you're right. the same name of both functions was causing the problem. I changed the name and its working fine. Thank you :)